# Google Kubernetes Engine - Ingress for Prometheus and Grafana not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I'm trying to install and access  Promethues and Grafana on K8 cluster on GKE .

- I created the cluster with 3 nodes.
- Installed Helm
- Install Prometheus Operator chart from stable repo
- Changed the node type from ClusterIp To NodePort for the services
  prometheus-operator-160067-prometheus
  prometheus-operator-1600675914-grafana
- Created an ingress with this yaml

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: my-ingress1
      annotations:
        # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce". 
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - path: /prometheus
            backend:
              serviceName: prometheus-operator-160067-prometheus 
              servicePort: 9090
          - path: /grafana
            backend:
              serviceName: prometheus-operator-1600675914-grafana
              servicePort: 80
```

After the ingress service is created the gke dashboard looks like this http://prntscr.com/ul18uf .
However , when i called the new endpoints I get the message "404 page not found "  http://prntscr.com/ul1bsm

Comment: What GKE version did you use? Which Helm chart did you use? Just for confirmation, you are using `gcp ingress` not `nginx ingress`.

Comment: Gke is 1.15.12-gke.20 , and kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce

Comment: Maybe check with only one service (say: prometheus) and path: /* ?

Comment: I did - same thing

Comment: `Modify Grafana Helm chart to use NodePort (service type is immutable so may need to delete and reinstall)`did you see [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/practical-monitoring-with-prometheus-grafana-part-iv-d4f3f995cc78) Did you try to reinstall grafana? Also, did you follow any tutorial? Did you configure firewall?